# to add newline for the dynamically created controls

Tags: c#, .net

I have created  buttons dynamically and when the button is clicked it should display checkboxes.for each button the checkboxes count will vary.i want display eg.if button1 has 4 checkboxes it should be displayed in a single line and if button 2 is clicked it should be displayed in the next line.i am not able to add newline character/control to the panel where button and the checkboxes are created.how to include newline character.its standalone application

```
checkBox checkbox = new CheckBox();
int count1 = pnltable.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().ToList().Count();
checkbox.Location = new Point(100, (65 * count1) + 2);
checkbox.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
checkbox.Size = new Size(60, 25);
checkbox.Name = "chk_" + dt1.Rows[j]["vcCover"].ToString();
checkbox.Tag = dt1.Rows[j]["vcTableId"].ToString();
checkbox.Text = dt1.Rows[j]["vcCover"].ToString();
pnltable.Controls.Add(checkbox);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the `CheckBox` location manually. You can set the `Top` property of `CheckBox` that is created by second button to sum to bottom value of `CheckBox` created by first along and some margin. For eg:

```
checkBoxFromButton2.Top = checkBoxFromButton1.Bottom + 5;
```

Please note that all checkboxes must be added to same container control for this to work.

Comment: pnltable.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />")); can this be added to window form